# Filter list of dictionaries with duplicate values at a certain key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
dic=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':9,'b':2,'c':2},{'a':5,'b':1,'c':2}]
```

I would like to filter out those dictionaries with recurring values for certain keys, such as in this case the key 'b' which has duplicate values in the first and second dictionaries in the list. I would like to remove the second entry

Quite simply, I would like my filtered list to look as follows:

```
filt_dic=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':5,'b':1,'c':2}]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another dictionary (or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to keep track of what values you have already seen for what keys. This dictionary will hold one `set` (for fast lookup) for each key of the original dict.

```
dic=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':9,'b':2,'c':2},{'a':5,'b':1,'c':2}]

seen = defaultdict(set)
filt_dic = []
for d in dic:
    if not any(d[k] in seen[k] for k in d):
        filt_dic.append(d)
        for k in d:
            seen[k].add(d[k])

print(filt_dic)
```

Afterwards, `filt_dic` is `[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}]` and `seen` is `{'a': set([1, 5]), 'c': set([2, 3]), 'b': set([1, 2])})`.