# How to filter out dictionaries with the same value for a certain key from a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of objects:

```
l = [{'name': 'Mike', 'age': 31},
     {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29},
     {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 44}]
```

I want to filter it based on the name, and because "Mike" is a duplicate in this case, I want to remove all entries with `name=Mike` (regardless of the age).

(i.e. to get the same list but without the entries that have `name=Mike`)

What's the best approach to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python filter list of dictionaries based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051573/python-filter-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-key-value)

Comment: no that one is looking for objects with a given key-values and returning them...in my case I don't have given values, and I need to look through al the list and find if any two (or more) have same key or not, then if yes remove both

Comment: Similar to [Filter list of dictionaries with duplicate values at a certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36067699/6045800) but this one wants to keep the first occurrence. Here we are talking about excluding the duplicates completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the counts of all names. Then [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the names that appear more than once:

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [{'name': 'Mike', 'age': 31},
     {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29},
     {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 44}]

names_count = Counter(d['name'] for d in l)
new_l = list(filter(lambda d: names_count[d['name']] == 1, l))
print(new_l)
```

Will give:

```
[{'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Collecting the dicts in a dict where keys are names and values are either the only dict with that name or `None` if the name is duplicated.

```
l = [{'name': 'Mike', 'age': 31},
     {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29},
     {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 44}]

D = {}
for d in l:
    n = d['name']
    D[n] = None if n in D else d
l[:] = filter(None, D.values())

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to implement it without using any function.

```
l = [{'name': 'Mike', 'age': 31},
     {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29},
     {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 44}]

name_dict = {}
for i in l:
    if i['name'] not in name_dict:
        name_dict[i['name']] = 1
    else:
        name_dict[i['name']] += 1

new_l = [d for d in l if name_dict[d['name']] == 1]

print(new_l)
```

outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Peter', 'age': 29}]
```